# SonarQube with Validate class from Apache Commons Lang3

Tags: java, sonarqube, apache-commons

I use the `Validate` class from the package `org.apache.commons.lang3` in my project to do nonNull-validation of variables ( https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html ).

I also use SonarQube for static code analysis and it always complains, when I use those variables afterwards, bc they *might be null there*.

Is there is a way to mark some methods as null checks for sonar? I would really like to avoid marking all occurences as false positives (this would not be an option really, since the analysis is integrated in my builds, before I have the opportunity to do so).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of SonarJava is installed on your SonarQube server ?

Comment: currently I have version `5.2 (build 13398)` installed. Will update to 5.3 this afternoon, but cannot see any fixes for this in the changelog: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA/fixforversion/14309/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugins.jira-development-integration-plugin:release-report-tabpanel

Comment: Ok, sorry for asking. I'm just stupid. I had two very similar variable names and checked the wrong one... Shouldn't work longer then 8 hours :P Sorry for bothering you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comment under the original post. Sorry for bothering...

> Ok, sorry for asking. I'm just stupid. I had two very similar variable names and checked the wrong one... Shouldn't work longer then 8 hours :P Sorry for bothering you!